Getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to run my Code
i am trying to follw this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/databricks-delta-lake-using-java
So i want to use spark with delta lake, but for my storage i use minio and not hdfs or s3 (But it is incorporated the same way).
Maybe someone can help me with my problem, so here is my code:
package minIO;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;


public class MinIOConnector {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Spark Excel file conversion")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
                .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "")
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "")
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "")
                .config("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", "false")
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file://./sparkapp")
                .config("spark.hadoop.io.native.lib.available", "false")
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.file.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem")
                .getOrCreate();



    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

            Employee emp = new Employee();

            emp.setEmpId("1234");

            emp.setEmpName("kiran");

            emp.setDeptName("Design dept");

            empList.add(emp);

            emp = new Employee();

            emp.setEmpId("3567");

            emp.setEmpName("raju");

            emp.setDeptName("IT");

            empList.add(emp);

Encoder<Employee> employeeEncoder = Encoders.bean(Employee.class);
                Dataset<org.apache.spark.sql.Row> empDF = spark.createDataset(empList, employeeEncoder).toDF();
                DataFrameWriter<Row> x = empDF.write().format("delta");

                x.save("s3a://test/test");
                System.out.println("after write");

                empDF = spark.read().format("delta").load("s3a://test/test");
                empDF.show();
    }

}

this is my pom.xml:
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>minio</groupId>
<artifactId>minio</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <!-- Your exact Hadoop version here-->
    <hadoop.version>3.0.0</hadoop.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-spark_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.199</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.13</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

my installed spark version is 3.5.1 from here https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
and hadoop 3.0.0 from here https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master
this is my stack trace:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most
recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
(BSDESK295.bsbanksysteme.com executor driver):
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native
Method)   at
org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)    at
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:160)
at
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:77)
at
org.apache.hadoop.util.BasicDiskValidator.checkStatus(BasicDiskValidator.java:32)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:330)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:393)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:476)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:213)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:479)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:185)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:167)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:657)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)     at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)  at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.(ParquetFileWriter.java:347)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.(ParquetFileWriter.java:314)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:484)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:422)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:411)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetUtils$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetUtils.scala:490)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.executeTask(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:412)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeWrite$2(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:274)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
at
org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)  at
org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
at
org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
at
org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
at
org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Driver stacktrace:    at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)  at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)   at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:989)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)    at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeWrite$1(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:263)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:295)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:234)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.write(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:214)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWrite.scala:440)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:398)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:371)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:147)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:246)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:242)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:147)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:235)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:232)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:147)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.writeFiles(WriteIntoDelta.scala:349)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.writeAndReturnCommitData(WriteIntoDelta.scala:312)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1(WriteIntoDelta.scala:106)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(WriteIntoDelta.scala:101)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:227)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.run(WriteIntoDelta.scala:101)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:201)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:107)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:98)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:859)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:388)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:240)
at minIO.MinIOConnector.main(MinIOConnector.java:78) Caused by:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native
Method)   at
org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)    at
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:160)
at
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:77)
at
org.apache.hadoop.util.BasicDiskValidator.checkStatus(BasicDiskValidator.java:32)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:330)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:393)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:476)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:213)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:479)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:185)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:167)
at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:657)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)     at
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)  at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.(ParquetFileWriter.java:347)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.(ParquetFileWriter.java:314)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:484)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:422)
at
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:411)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetUtils$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetUtils.scala:490)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.executeTask(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:412)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeWrite$2(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:274)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
at
org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)  at
org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
at
org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
at
org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
at
org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)


what is the error and stack trace?

I am sorry, I have added it now!

Does this answer your question? Maven - UnsatisfiedLinkError with java.library.path

Thanks for the comment, but I don't think so. At least I don't know what I should put there for my dependency.

I've now updated my pom.xml that it looks like this and it works now :)
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>mongodb</groupId>
<artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <!-- Your exact Hadoop version here-->
    <hadoop.version>3.3.4</hadoop.version>
    <jackson.version>2.15.0</jackson.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20230227</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
        <artifactId>delta-spark_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
        <artifactId>delta-core_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
        <artifactId>delta-storage</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.262</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


In order to use the winutils on higher spark versions you need to have the hadoop.dll on the windows PATH.
Alternatively use barenakedfs: https://github.com/globalmentor/hadoop-bare-naked-local-fs
Configure via this link.  Per this usage you must register before spark starts:
def registerFS(sparkSessionBuilder: SparkSession.Builder): SparkSession.Builder =
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows"))
      sparkSessionBuilder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.file.impl",classOf[BareLocalFileSystem].getName)
    else
      sparkSessionBuilder

If you must use winutils, per the site's instructions use: https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils for the correct version.  For 3.5.1 it's probably https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-3.3.5/bin (based on POMs).

Thanks for the answer, but the hadoop.dll is already in my path as it is %HADOOP_HOME%\bin and the dll file is in my bin folder

@juliastoelli also updated answer as the winutils is not matching.

sadly that did not work for me, I still get the same error. But thank you!

just in case - both your pom AND your winuntils hadoop versions must match.  (your pom had 3.0)

Yes, I've updated both of them.
